# Evaluate an integral over $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and Green's Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $p(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$ be a smooth function in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ decaying sufficiently rapid as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$. Why is $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}p_{x_{i}}\, dx = 0?$$
By the Gauss-Green Theorem, if we were integrating over a bounded region $U$, then $$\int_{U}p_{x_{i}}\, dx = \int_{\partial U}p\nu^{i}\, dS$$ where $\nu$ is the outer unit normal, but I don't know what to do if we are working over $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "decaying sufficiently rapidly" guarantees that the triple integral of $p$ exists, and so it agrees with the iterated integrals. You have
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^3}p_{x_1}dx=\int_{\mathbb R^2}\left(\lim_{a\to\infty,b\to-\infty
}\int_a^b\,p_{x_1}\,dx_1\right)\,dx_2\,dx_3\\
=\int_{\mathbb R^2}\,\lim_{a\to\infty,b\to-\infty}\left[p(a,x_2,x_3)-p(b,x_2,x_3)\right]\,dx_2\,dx_3\\
=0
$$
The limit is zero because $p$ decays to zero at infinity.